# Porque razão há inconsistências na minha página responsiva em ecras com a mesma resolução?

Tags: css, front-end

Estou a desenvolver uma Landing Page responsiva. A página comporta-se da seguinte maneira:

Maior que 1920px (Tem a mesma root Styling, mas centra a página ao centro);
1920px(root) Full Styled;
1800px  Ajustada;
1600px  Ajustada;
1450px  Ajustada;
1366px  Full Styled;
1150px  Ajustada;
1000px  Ajustada;
900px   Ajustada;
800px   Full Styled;
760px   Ajustada;
600px   Full Styled;
520px   Ajustada;
420px   Ajustada;
320px   Full Styled;

A minha duvida encontra-se na resolução 320px. No meu telemovel (320x570) a página aparece conforme a visionei, mas no telemovel de uma colega que supostamente tem uma resolução equivalente os estilos comportam-se como se a width fosse menor que 320px.
Não compreendo esta inconsistencia.
Como é o meu primeiro projecto responsive gostaria de compreender melhor o que esta acontecer.

Comment: Olá Bruno, talvez a gente consiga ajudar-lhe melhor se adicionares algum trecho de teu CSS à pergunta (em especial a parte que controla as resoluções). Talvez o que esteja a acontecer seja por causa de alguma consideração do dispositivo com relação a densidade de pixels por polegada, ou talvez o telemóvel do seu colega esteja a informar ao sistema uma resolução diferente da que tem.

Comment: Outra coisa a considerar é que o CSS normalmente considera o tamanho da janela, não a resolução do ecrã... Se o navegador do seu colega não ocupar toda a tela de seu telemóvel, então não se comportará como o estilo indicado para 320px.

Comment: Acho que foi por essa mesma razão... Ajustei a página a 310px e ja se comporta como devia :)